# func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts...) - can't copy the URL via FileManager.copyItem()

Tags: ios, swift, url, copy, file-permissions

Not sure why I get this error trying to copy a file that's passed to my app via openURLContexts.  The source file is one on my iCloud drive that I tapped that opened up my app.

Interestingly I *can* read the incoming URL (JSON), so the file is actually readable by me, but if I try to copy it to a temporary directory the iCloud ubiquity container it generates this exception.

tempDir path= /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E4886514-A6C5-41FE-A844-D57C40D10F24/tmp/someFile

> Error copying file to temporary directory: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “somefile” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/somefile, NSUnderlyingError=0x2819ac090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
        let filename = url.lastPathComponent            
        // Cache it a temporary location so we can keep the URL valid and readable
        let tempDirURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: tempDirURL)
        } catch {
            print("Error copying file to temporary directory: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check to see if the file must be opened in place. This is done by looking at the `openInPlace` property of the URL context options.

If that is set then you must use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()/stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on the URL with your access in between.

Here's the updated scene delegate method:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let urlContext = URLContexts.first else { return }

    let url = urlContext.url
    let filename = url.lastPathComponent
    let openInPlace = urlContext.options.openInPlace

    // Cache it a temporary location so we can keep the URL valid and readable
    let tempDirURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

    defer {
        if openInPlace {
            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
    }

    do {
        if !openInPlace || url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: tempDirURL)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error copying file to temporary directory: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I just solved this exact issue in my own (Objective-C) app earlier today. Good timing.

Comment: Do note that your code (and my answer) assumes that the URL being requested is a file URL. If your app also supports a custom scheme then you need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. ChatGPT finally got around to suggesting that at the same time. Everyone's got good timing! I do have LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace set true in info.plist but I wasn't aware of that side-effect. Thanks again!